# What I need to install for getting java pattern wizard on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Any one know what I need to install to getting google java pattern wizard (below url) on eclipse?

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/patterns/pattern_wizard

I have installed WindowBuilder Pro however no such option find in my eclipse.

My eclipse is using juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be included in **CodePro**, but [the current version (CodePro Analytix) doesn't have this feature any more](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/codepro-analytix/xi1o5M4U9ks).